# How to count number of times a recurring task is marked done after logging is enabled?

Tags: org-mode

I had a task in my org file for which I wanted to keep track of the number of times a task is marked as DONE when it's recurring.

I am logging my change to the drawer and thus it should be possible to get the count.

Currently, I count the number of times the task was executed manually but want to automate this effort. This option would help me keep track of the number of times the task was marked DONE. It would also be amazing if we could reset the count after getting it done a fixed number of times.

I am not a programmer so I'm struggling with implementing a solution in elisp to do the same.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We write two functions: one to count the number of DONE entries in the drawer and one to add the count as a property to the headline. Here's an example Org mode document delineating the basic assumptions:

```
* TODO foo
  SCHEDULED: <2020-07-07 Tue +1d>
  :PROPERTIES:
  :LOG_INTO_DRAWER: logging
  :VISIBILITY: folded
  :LAST_REPEAT: [2020-07-01 Wed 16:03]
  :END:
:logging:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-07-01 Wed 16:03]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-07-01 Wed 16:03]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-07-01 Wed 16:03]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-07-01 Wed 15:58]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-07-01 Wed 13:38]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-07-01 Wed 13:38]
:END:
```

We assume that there is a `LOG_INTO_DRAWER` property naming the drawer where the logging is done (`logging` in this case), and we have transitioned to DONE a number of times.

Here's the (decidedly less clunky, thanks to @erikstokes's comment) code:

```el
(defun ndk/count-done ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    ;; we need to end up *before* the start of the drawer in order
    ;; to parse it correctly, so we back up one line from where org-log-beginning tells us.
    (goto-char (org-log-beginning))
    (forward-line -1)
    (let ((contents (cadr (org-element-drawer-parser nil nil))))
      (count-lines (plist-get contents :contents-begin)
                   (plist-get contents :contents-end)))))

(defun ndk/put-count ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((count (ndk/count-done)))
    (org-entry-put (point) "done-count" (format "%d" count))))
```

We assume that `point` is at the beginning of the headline. Both functions are declared `interactive` so you can call them with `M-x ndk/count-done` or `M-x ndk/put-count` for debugging, but only the second really needs to be.

So if you place the cursor on the `*` of the headline and say `M-x ndk/count-done` you should  get `6` as a result in the echo area. The function gets to the beginning of the log and then calls `org-element-drawer-parser` to parse the drawer and extract the beginning and end of the contents of the drawer. It then passes those two to `count-lines` and returns the result.

Doing `M-x ndk/put-count` at the same point calls the previous function to count the number of `DONE` lines and then inserts the count as a property `done-count` in the property drawer.

Resetting the count after every N times that the task is done is just a matter of calculating a remainder when dividing the count by N. Here's an implementation where N is obtained as the value of the `reset-count` property (but if there is no such property, we take N=10):

```el
(defun ndk/count (count)
  (let* ((reset-count-prop (org-entry-get (point) "reset-count"))
         (reset-count (or (and reset-count-prop (string-to-number reset-count-prop))
                          10)))
    (% count reset-count)))

(defun ndk/put-count ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((count (ndk/count-done)))
    (org-entry-put (point) "done-count" (format "%d" (ndk/count count)))))
```

Comment: Rather than searching for the starting of the logging drawer, the function `org-log-beginning` returns the start of the logs, even if something is hiding it

Comment: Thanks! That takes care of most of the clunkiness.

Comment: @erikstokes - thanks for the fix. Embarassing...

Comment: The function seems to be giving me a count one lower than the actual. I edited the function ndk/put-count () with  (org-entry-put (point) "done-count" (format "%d" (+ count 1)) to get the accurate number. This might be due to the function not counting the start or the end line. Is there a way to get the reset count from a property value in the drawer so that I can have different reset number for different tasks rather than hard coding the value?

Comment: You mean you get 5 for the example above? I hope not...

Comment: Ah, you are right: it seems that `org-log-beginning` gets me one line further in than my clunky solution, so I have to compensate. I'll check some more first (it's been embarassing enough already) and then fix the answer and add the reset count in a property as well. Stay tuned...

Comment: Here' s hoping that I haven't screwed up anything - please take a look and let me know if there are problems still.

Comment: One final(?) small change: backing up one line from where `org-log-beginning` tells us, rather than one char. We end up at the beginning of the line with the drawer name, which seems more natural to me.

Comment: Thanks @NickD this seems to be working.